# java null point exception, apache poi, java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, apache-poi

I have a problem in this code:

```
public static void add(MonthRequirementInformation[] list,AdditiveInformation[] list1) throws IOException{

**for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){**

            for(int j=0;j<PGENcode.length;j++){

                if(list[i].getPGEN()==PGENcode[i]){

                    **for(int k=0;k<list1.length;k++){**

                        if(list1[k].getComponentCode()==AdditiveCode[j]){

                            list1[k].change_xMonthReq(list[i].getMonthx()*AdditiveAmount[j]);
                            list1[k].change_yMonthReq(list[i].getMonthy()*AdditiveAmount[j]);
                            list1[k].change_zMonthReq(list[i].getMonthz()*AdditiveAmount[j]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

There's a lot of other stuff also happening in this function, but I'll leave it out, cause it really doesnt matter.

this is how my main looks:

```
public static void main(String[] agrv) throws IOException{

        MonthRequirementInformation[] list=null;
        AdditiveInformation[] list1=null;

        Workbook inputWb=readWorkbook();

        Sheet RequimentWs=inputWb.getSheet("PGEN List");    
        int r=RequimentWs.getLastRowNum()+1;
        fillMonthReqObj(RequimentWs,r,list);

        Sheet AdditveWs=inputWb.getSheet("Additive List");
        int r1=AdditveWs.getLastRowNum()+1;
        fillAddInfoObj(AdditveWs,r1,list1);

        add(list,list1);
        finalOutput(list1);


    }
```

to explain the problem: 
im getting a java null point exception, on the stared lines in the function add, and i have no idea why this is happening. 
could anyone figure out why this is happening.

Comment: `list` is null. Nice and simple.

Comment: variable 'list' is never being instantiated!

Answer (score 2):

When do you instantiate these?

```
MonthRequirementInformation[] list=null;
AdditiveInformation[] list1=null;
```

You never create the array, so when you call `length` on the objects, it throws an `NPE`.

***NOTE***: A `NullPointerException` is one of the most common exceptions I see on here. In future, try to observe where the exception is occurring, what object is throwing the exception, and if that object has been intanciated. This helps to rule out the obvious situation, which is what has happened now.

Comment: they are being instantiated in two functions: 
public static void fillMonthReqObj(Sheet ws, int r, MonthRequirementInformation[] list );
public static void fillAddInfoObj(Sheet ws, int r,AdditiveInformation[] list1);

Comment: Apparently they are not, given that `list` is the object throwing the `NPE`. Show us the code for the methods that fills one of the lists.

Comment: Oh i get it, i should call these functions inside the function add() right?

Comment: instead of calling them in main()?

Comment: No, you can call it before if you want. An array is a type of Java object, so updating the object will reflect in all references to that `Object`.

Comment: the functions that fill they arrays of objects work perfectly 
i have already tested it out

Comment: Well at the moment, they appear to be the most obvious problem, if the code you have provided is what is running.